# Let $K$ be a convex subset of $X$.I need prove:each $x \in X$ has at most one best approximation in $K$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $K$ be a convex subset of $X$.I need prove:each $x \in X$ has at most one best approximation in $K$

Comment: What arguments have you tried so far?

Comment: This depends on the norm of $X$. The claim is true, e.g., for Hilbert spaces but it is wrong for $X=\mathbb R^2$ with the norm $(\|(x,y)\|_\infty=\max\{|x|,|y|\}$.

Comment: My asked is in inner product space and we know $y_{0}$is a best approximation if $||x-y_{0}||=d(x,K)$.                                               
 but why you used  $arg min||•||^{2}$.                                                         
  What is your argument ?you write:It is at most single valued because the objective function is strongly convex.and ""Since the set K is convex, the mapping (Id+NK)−1 is at most single valued""

Comment: I know prove of ""each convex proximinal set is chebyshev""But i need prove case""no best approximation of x in K""in question

Answer (score 0):

The best approximation $y\in K$ of a point $x\in X$ is given by

$$y \in \arg\min\limits_{u\in K}\frac{1}{2}\|x-u\|^2$$

First notice that the set on the right hand side can be empty, in which case there is no best approximation of $x$ in $K$. Assume, then, that it is not empty. It is at most single valued because the objective function is strongly convex. Furthermore, taking the subdifferential, the first order optimality condition is

$$0 \in y-x + N_K(y)\implies y\in(Id + N_K)^{-1}x.$$

Since the set $K$ is convex, the mapping $(Id + N_K)^{-1}$ is at most single valued.